# Don't know how to decode encoded text I just wropte in Python

Tags: python, encryption

I have this piece of code that will encrypt any text input by the user into numbers as shown below:

code:

```
text = input()

def encrypt(t):
    chars = list(text)
    allowed_characters = list(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.?!")

    for char in chars:
        for i in allowed_characters:
            if char == i:
                chars[chars.index(char)] = allowed_characters.index(i)
    return chars

print(encrypt(text))
```

Output: (I input dogs as the text to be encrypted)

```
[4, 15, 7, 19]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what problem did you encounter? On another note, this is encoding and not encryption, these have different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict for encoding and decoding with the strings.
It woudl be really simpler than list for this case.
Pleasae check this code.

```
ac = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.?!"
dict_e = { k:v for v, k in enumerate(ac)}
dict_d = { k:v for k, v in enumerate(ac)}

def encrypt(t):
  return [dict_e[x] for x in t]
def decode(t):
  return [dict_d[x] for x in t]

text = input()
print(encrypt(text))

print(''.join(decode(encrypt(text))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i run the code i get this error message: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found. It seems that the final part of your code with ''.join is not recognized by my compiler.

Comment: @Bt7274 - well, I checked again and get the correct output with dogs. Would you please let me know which line has the error?

Comment: It appears to be the final line of the code.

Comment: Well, `decode(encrypt(text))` returns [ 'd', 'o', 'g', 's']. The return is joined  with ''. The line is working on my interpreter. Can you give me the error message?